# How do I get the tag of the user I am targeting when making a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot where you type "&insult ".  But I don't know how to assign the users tag that I am targeting to a variable (eg: var member).

Comment: Get the ID of the user you want to tag (Ideally by finding it through the server members), and in the message use `<@ID_OF_USER>`

Comment: Maybe you looking for something like that  `let user = message.mentions.users.first()`